# How do I compute the residue at this pole?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$ f(z) = \frac{e^{az}}{1 + e^z} \qquad (0 < a < 1) $$ I know this function has poles at $z = (2k + 1) i \pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let's say I need to find the residue at the pole $z = \pi i$. How would I compute this? I tried using the formula $$ Res(f(z), z= \pi i) = \lim_{z \to \pi i} (z - z_0) f(z)$$ but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can use the series expansion of $f(z)$ about $z=i\pi$ and take the coefficient of the $(z-i\pi)^{-1}$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\zeta=z-i \pi$.  Then the function of $\zeta$ is

$$\frac{e^{i a (\zeta+i \pi)}}{1+e^{(\zeta+ i \pi)}} = e^{i \pi a} \frac{e^{i a \zeta}}{1-e^{\zeta}}$$

Now take the Laurent expansion of this about $\zeta=0$ and see that the coefficient of $\zeta^{-1}$ is clearly $-e^{i \pi a}$.

Comment: I tried taking the Laurent expansion, but still I don't see that the coefficient is $-e^{i \pi a}$. I expand the denominator as a geometric series right? And the numerator is just complex exponential expansion?

Comment: @Kamil: That's right.  The $1$'s cancel in the denominator, leaving a $\zeta$ as the leading term.  The rest should be simple.

Comment: Ah, I see it now! Thank you